# Apache wicket Base64 encode the Ajax form data before submission

Tags: ajax, wicket

Our application(based on Apache Wicket framework) actively uses Ajax in the form of AjaxButton, AjaxLinks etc. We want to encode the form data request in Base64 format before form submission and later decode it just after form submission. Basically, only the Base 64 encoded text will be a part of request data.

In other applications which uses javascript and java(struts framework), we have applied the encoding logic in javascript before document.form.submit and then on Java/server side , the decoding logic is applied.

Any idea how can we achieve the same in Apache wicket which follows Ajax form submission logic?

We tried AjaxCallListener but could not get hold of the request data. Hence, could not apply the encoding logic on the request

Answer (score 0):

At the server side it should be easy to intercept the parameters' read by extending ServletWebRequest and overriding [generatePostParameters()](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/4affb7b18424e40663239ac9c93d9ec33a432541/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/servlet/ServletWebRequest.java#L278) method.

Wicket uses jQuery to make the Ajax calls. But I see no way how to manipulate the `data` [parameter](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/4affb7b18424e40663239ac9c93d9ec33a432541/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.js#L707) before making the call.